# open_basedir restriction in effect - since update

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade, magento-upgrade

Since updating to the newest **1.9 version** I get this **error** attached to a mail - **every 5 Minutes**...

I can't figure out what exactly is the problem.

```
ERR (3): Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(var/cookie) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/domain.de/:/tmp/)  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php on line 157
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert to answer this kind of questions. But from the error, I smell fishy with your PHP settings of `open_basedir`. The error says, there is some restriction in effect and complains that cookie file is not in allowed paths.

So the solution would be either remove the `open_basedir` restriction by modifying your PHP configuration (Please do research on this, I am not an expert to suggest something) or add `var/cookie` file path.

Hope that will give some insights to resolve this issue.

### Some references

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following to my open_basedir settings in Plesk Onyx:

`{WEBSPACEROOT}/:{TMP}/:var/cookie:{WEBSPACEROOT}/httpdocs/var/cookie:{WEBSPACEROOT}/var/cookie`

I don't know which of the three 'var/cookie'-entrys does the job - but my Problem is gone!

Thank you Rajeev for the Links :)